# How to detect when user reached the destination in Google Map? I am launching Google Map via intent from my app

Tags: android, google-maps

This is how I am launching google Map. Now I want to detect when user reached the destination.

```
    String uri = String.format(Locale.ENGLISH, "http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr=%f,%f (%s)", drplat, drplong, getAddresss(drplat, drplong));
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
            intent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            try
            {
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
            catch(ActivityNotFoundException ex)
            {
                try
                {
                    Intent unrestrictedIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri));
                   context.startActivity(unrestrictedIntent);
                }
                catch(ActivityNotFoundException innerEx)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Please install a maps application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LocationManager` class, and especially it's `addProximityAlert` member function. The `PendingIntent` you specify will be triggered each time the phone enters or leaves the area defined by the location and the radius provided.

[addProximityAlert](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#addProximityAlert(double,%20double,%20float,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent))

Comment: Thanks @Zelig63 . Now i am working on it and It would br very helpful if you can provide me a demo.If not possible then no problem and Thanks again.